# Solve the system of equations by first letting A=1/x, B=1/y and C=1/z.

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\begin{cases}\frac{12}{x} -\frac{12}{y} = 7\\\frac3x + \frac4y =0\end{cases}$$

So I know how to do a portion of this but our teacher wants us to use matrices to solve all systems of equations in our linear algebra class. I need some help with the matrix part. Here is my work so far:

$$\begin{cases}
12A - 12B = 7\\
3A +4B = 0\end{cases}$$

From here I would normally do some form of elimination and end up with $B = -4$ and then back sub into one of the equations to find a value for $A$. However as stated above, our professor only wants us to use matrices to find our solutions.
$$\begin{bmatrix}12&-12&\vert&7\\3&4&\vert&0\end{bmatrix}$$

From here I am unsure what to do to put the matrix in echelon form so that I can find a solution. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: How did you do your elimination to get $B=-4$? You could do the same thing with the lines of your matrix.

Comment: Are you familiar with the matrix reducing rules? If so, it's a pretty simple application to reduce the $2\times 2$ matrix you have while also adjusting the separate column accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The allowable row operations are the same as you are used to using with equations.  You can multiply a row by any constant, add any multiple of one row to another, or swap rows.  For a $2 \times 2$ matrix we just need to get the lower left corner to be zero.  You may also need the first element in each row to be a $1$, which I will assume.  First multiply the first row by $\frac 1{12}$, then add $-3$ times the first to the second to produce the zero, finally multiply the second by $\frac 17$

$$\begin{bmatrix}12&-12&\vert&7\\3&4&\vert&0\end{bmatrix}\to\\
\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&\vert&\frac 7{12}\\3&4&\vert&0\end{bmatrix}\to\\
\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&\vert&\frac 7{12}\\0&7&\vert&-\frac{21}{12}\end{bmatrix}\to\\
\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&\vert&\frac 7{12}\\0&1&\vert&-\frac{3}{12}\end{bmatrix}$$